# FromJSON make a list from multiple fields

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have an object to parse that looks a bit like this :

```
{
  "data":
  [
    {
      "virtio0": "some text",
      "virtio1": "blah",
      "ide2": "some other text",
      "cores": 1,
      "mem": 512,
      ...
    },
    {
      // The same ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I basically want to parse that into a [VM], but my problem is those numbered fields. Depending on the VM config, it might or might not have virtioX fields, ideX fields .. and I don't see a way to know in advance, nor to guess the numbers.
I was thinking the best might be to define a Disk type that would contain something like Virtio | Sata | IDE and so on for the type, and a Text field for the value, then have each VM have a [Disk] in it's type. Something like this :

```
data DiskType = Virtio | Sata | IDE
data Disk     = Disk {diskType :: DiskType, diskPath :: Text}
data VM       = VM {cores :: Int, disks :: [Disk], mem :: Int, ...}
```

That would be great, but how do I parse those random fields that I have directly inside the VM json object into a list ?

Comment: I would just store the keys as additional values.

Comment: What do you mean ? I have basically no idea of how Aeson works, I recently figured out how to use v .: "stuff" to use different names, maybe use a condition, but that's about it. And the doc is a bit hairy for me

Comment: I'm not too familiar with what Aeson supports. But one approach is to use `decode` into an `Object` type. And parse that object into your data types. The section "Decoding a mixed-type object" might be useful to look at.

Comment: Do you create this json object or is it created by some program? I mean, can you get rid of `X` suffix in `"virtioX"` and `"ideX"`?

Comment: Ah, no I have no control over the original json, it's the Proxmox API. As for "Decoding a mixed-type object" thanks, I'll take a look at that !

Comment: Alright then. But, also, you might find handy `.:?` operator: it is the same as `.:` but it returns `Maybe a` if json field is missing. It allows you to parse data types with maybe fields like `data D = D (Maybe Int)`.

Comment: You can modify the original JSON by a function first: standardize :: Value -> Value. This function will turn all VirtioX to virtio, and ideX to ide. Then you can use `.:?` operator

Comment: My problem isn't the fact that there is a number, it's that there might be 9 virtio and 2 ide, for example. Depending on how many disks and what types of disks the VM has, that's why I'd like to parse it as a list instead.

Comment: I've edited the json to show that, there could be multiple of each types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't consider myself a Haskell expert, and even less of an Aeson expert, I think I've found something that works. Take it for what it is.

The following code all makes use of this module declaration and these imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<|>))
import Data.Aeson
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import Data.HashMap.Lazy (HashMap, foldlWithKey')
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Data.Text (Text, stripPrefix, unpack)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
```

I changed the type declarations slightly:

```
data DiskType = Virtio | Sata | IDE deriving (Show)
data Disk =
  Disk { diskType :: DiskType, diskNumber :: Int, diskPath :: Text }
  deriving (Show)
data VM = VM { cores :: Int, disks :: [Disk], mem :: Int } deriving (Show)
```

The most notable difference is that I added `diskNumber` to the `Disk` type, so that it can capture both the number after the disk type, as well as the text associated with the disk property.

The other change was that I made all types be instances of `Show`. This was only to be able to test whether or not my code works.

First, I defined a little helper function that can find the number after a given prefix:

```
findNumber :: Read a => Text -> Text -> Maybe a
findNumber prefix candidate =
  stripPrefix prefix candidate >>= (readMaybe . unpack)
```

Examples:

```
*Main Data.Text> findNumber (pack "ide") (pack "ide2") :: Maybe Int
Just 2
*Main Data.Text> findNumber (pack "sata") (pack "sata0") :: Maybe Int
Just 0
*Main Data.Text> findNumber (pack "foo") (pack "bar") :: Maybe Int
Nothing
```

This enabled me to write a function that finds all the disks in an `Object`:

```
findDisks :: HashMap Text Value -> [Disk]
findDisks = foldlWithKey' folder []
  where
    findVirtio k s = flip (Disk Virtio) s <$> findNumber "virtio" k
    findSata   k s = flip (Disk Sata)   s <$> findNumber "sata"   k
    findIde    k s = flip (Disk IDE)    s <$> findNumber "ide"    k
    folder acc k (String s) =
      acc ++ toList (findVirtio k s <|> findSata k s <|> findIde k s)
    folder acc _ _ = acc
```

`Object` is a type alias for `HashMap Text Value`, so this function takes an `Object` as input, and returns a list of the `Disk` values that it could find.

This is enough to define an instance of `FromJSON` for `VM`:

```
instance FromJSON VM where
  parseJSON = withObject "VM" $ \o -> do
    let disks = findDisks o
    cores <- o .: "cores"
    mem   <- o .: "mem"
    return $ VM cores disks mem
```

In order to test that this works, I created this JSON string:

```
myJson :: ByteString
myJson =
  "[\
    \{\
      \\"virtio0\": \"some text\",\
      \\"virtio1\": \"blah\",\
      \\"ide2\": \"some other text\",\
      \\"cores\": 1,\
      \\"mem\": 512\
    \}\
  \]"
```

and used it from `main`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let vms = decode myJson :: Maybe [VM]
  print vms
```

When executed, it prints the decoded value:

```
Just [VM {cores = 1, disks = [Disk {diskType = IDE, diskNumber = 2, diskPath = "some other text"},Disk {diskType = Virtio, diskNumber = 1, diskPath = "blah"},Disk {diskType = Virtio, diskNumber = 0, diskPath = "some text"}], mem = 512}]
```

Notice that the JSON parsed here is simply an array of VM objects. I didn't include the outer container object with the `data` property, but if you need help with that, I think that ought to be a separate question :)

Comment: Well, I just tested this and it does exactly what I need ! Thanks a lot for this, I can't say I understand it all so it looks like I have a bit of reading to do :)

Answer (score 1):

If as you said there are only 9 virtio and 2 ide, one simple and perhaps not so elegent way to do is to use the asum function from Data.Foldable (which is generalised choice from various parsing libraries)

```
import Control.Applicative


instance FromJSON VM where
  parseJSON = withObject "VM" $ \o -> do
    cores <- o .: "cores"
    mem   <- o .: "mem"
    disk  <- optional $ asum [
      o .: "virtio0",
      o .: "virtio1",
      o .: "virtio2",
    return VM{..}
```

I haven't tried the code yet. For further reference, see this [link](https://artyom.me/aeson#more-interesting-choices) for a comprehensive guide of haskell JSON parsing with the Aeson library.

Comment: Well I can't tell how many there will be, could be 0, could be 10, could be 50. But I imagine I could have it loop on 99 iterations or something like that, I imagine there must be a maximum ..