# how to pptable the dynamic json String useing aeson in haskell

Tags: haskell, aeson

I want to use the `pptable` and the `aeson` lib to change the json string to   table display in console.

The json string come from the es table, it just like

```
{
"hits": {
 "hits": [
  {
   "_type": "tableName", 
   "_routing": "key", 
   "_source": {
    "col1": 1, 
    "col2": 0, 
    "col3": "1", 
    "col4": "2", 
    "col5": 2824, 
    "col6": "2018-05-26 22:49:24"
   }, 
   "_score": 11.97, 
   "_index": "mysql_", 
   "_id": "9"
  }
 ], 
 "total": 1, 
 "max_score": 11.97
}, 
"_shards": {
 "successful": 30, 
 "failed": 0, 
 "total": 30
}, 
"took": 60, 
"timed_out": false
}
```

And I want to display a table just like

```
  +----------------------------------------------------------+
  |col1|  col2 | col3 | col4 |   col5   |    col6            |
  |  1 | 0     |  1   | 2    | 2824     | 2018-05-26 22:49:24|
  +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can pase the json String to aeson Object and filter the `_source` sub object. But the Object type not deriving Generic.

So I have no idea how to do with it.

Comment: Is the problem related to Aeson or pptable? I understand that you have problems with the `_source` object in the JSON. Is the table relevant to the question, though? Is the rest of the JSON structure important? What have you tried and where are you having problems? Are there irrelevant parts of the above data structures that you could remove and still reproduce the problem? Can you post [an MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The content of the `_source` will change dynamicly . It dependent on the sql query.    So I can not define the `_source` constractor

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44514645/126014

Comment: I guess you misunderstand what I means. My Input like `select * from table1` or `select id, name from tabble2`, so the `_resource` json with dynamic object with unknown keys and values. So I can not define a type , only I can do is use HashMap